# Wifi not working on Acer Aspire 5570Z

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop, acer

The Ethernet works but the wifi does not. I have updated everything and it had no help. And I know that it works because less then 24 hours ago it had windows vista on it and would work. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add wireless firmware for Linux. Open your terminal and copy/paste this command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

It's worked for me a couple of times. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, This however did not work. Do you have any other ideas?